# Specify condition for negative sampling in gensim word2vec

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm training word2vec model where each word belongs to a specific class.

I want my embeddings to learn differences of words within each class, but don't want them to learn the differences between classes.

This can be achieved by negative sampling from only the words of same class as the target word.

In gensim [word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), we can specify the number of words to negative sample using `negative` parameter, but it doesn't mention any options to modify/filter the sampling function.

Is there any method to achieve this?

**Update:**

Consider the classes to be like languages. So I have words from different languages. In training data, each sentence/document contains mostly words from same language, but sometimes from other languages.

Now I want embeddings where words with similar meanings are together irrespective of the language.

But because words from different languages do not occur together as frequently as words from same language, the embeddings basically groups words from same language together.

Because of this, I wanted to try negative sampling target words with words from same language so that it learns to distinguish the words within same language.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "learn differences of words within each class, but don't want them to learn the differences between classes", or what benefit you'd hope to achieve.

If words co-occur in training texts, the word2vec training algorithm will try to predict neighboring words, and the end-results are the useful word-vectors.

If two words shouldn't have any influence on each other, you could preprocess your texts so they never co-occur. For example, if you have three classes of words, and your text corpus naturally includes a mixture of all three classes in each, you could filter the corpus into three separate corpuses. Each corpus would feature the words of one class, and drop the words of the other classes. Then you could train 3 separate `Word2Vec` models from the 3 corpuses.

But I'm not sure why you'd want to do that: the word-vectors from each corpus/model wouldn't be usefully comparable. I've not seen any work that does that, nor can I imagine a benefit – while it seems to throw away exactly the subtle relationships most people want from word2vec.

Comment: Consider the classes to be like languages. So I have words from different languages. In training data, each sentence/document contains mostly words from same language, but sometimes from other languages.

Comment: Now I want embeddings where words with similar meanings are together irrespective of the language.

Comment: But because words from different languages do not occur together as frequently as words from same language, the embeddings basically groups words from same language together.

Comment: Because of this, I wanted to try negative sampling target words with words from same language so that it learns to distinguish the words within same language.

Comment: A small, natural number of mixed-language examples probably won't hurt the model, and might even help – inducing some mildly useful cross-language relationships. But if you really want 5 distinct per-language models, filtering the corpus into 5 different monolingual datasets should work better than any custom limitations that are only imposed on the choice of negative-examples in negative-sampling.

Comment: I don't want distinct models. I want same model with similar meaning words grouped together irrespective of language.

Comment: Language was just an example. My actual application is a recommendation system. And the number of classes is of the order of thousands.

Comment: If you want one model, you should train everything together. There's no need to avoid the cross-influence between your classes - that's exactly what can make vectors for words of different classes interpretable vs each other. (You could test my suggestion of filtering each text example into variants that stay within one class of words, but still train those examples together. I think that would approximate the kind of negative-sampling-layer effect you request. But I don't know, and kind of doubt, it would give good results, because again: it's the natural co-occurrences that make w2v work.)

Comment: You could also look into a parameter to adjust the negative-sampling's weighting of rare-vs-frequent words, `ns_exponent`, which was made adjustable in recent versions of gensim after a research paper suggested non-default values could especially help in recommendation systems. (I think the non-default values suggested work in somewhat the **opposite** direction of your request, putting rarer words into **more** cross-influence situations.) More details & a link to the paper are in the docs for the parameter: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec

Comment: @gojomo  -: If you are working on building something like the thing in this paper (by Yahoo) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01869.pdf, then you do need custom negative sampling tricks otherwise you can't do that. In the paper, the search links which show up on top but weren't clicked by the suer serve as the negative samples.